# NumberFormatException while converting a string to an integer value in java

Tags: java, exception, numberformatexception

When I'm trying to parse the input1 string to an integer value it's rising a NumberFormatException.I've tried replacing the spaces if any in the string but it didn't work for me.

```
int number = 0;
 String input1 = "12345354987"; 
 try{
   ip = Integer.parseInt(input1);

  }catch(NumberFormatException e){
        System.out.println("not a number");
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried looking at the stack trace for e? Exceptions frequently contain very useful information.

Comment: @Eran 
Thanks, and it worked for me..!

Comment: See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#MAX_VALUE . 

MAX_VALUE = 2_147_483_647

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because the Number in String is out of Integer range, If you really need this than use BigInteger for large values like this :

```
 String input1 = "12345354"; 
         BigInteger ib =new BigInteger(input1);
         System.out.println(ib);
```

or
For small values that can fit in Long range you can use :

```
String input1 = "1234535455"; 
           Long ip = Long.parseLong(input1);
           System.out.println(ip);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
12345354987 > 2,147,483,64
```

Integer max range is `2,147,483,647` and you are crossing it. You may use Long or BigDecimal for big numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Your number is greater then integer Max value please use long then try parsing.